# select a colum from data frame column in a function

Tags: r, function

I can't find the way to select a variable from a data.frame using a function.
I tried things like

```
modDiagnosis<-function<-(x){
  #prediction
  pred<-prediction(test[,x],test$VAR2)
}
```

or

```
modDiagnosis<-function<-(x){
  vars<-deparse(substitute(x))
  #prediction
  pred<-prediction(test[,vars],test$VAR2)
}
```

but always get the same error

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(test, , x) : object 'x' not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you fix the typos `function<-(x)`  also, have you tried `pred<-prediction(test[,x],test$VAR2)` instead of the `vars <- deparse...`  A reproducible example would be helpful.  No idea about the package that has `prediction` funciton

Comment: @akrun Thanks for your response.Sorry, I don't know how to fix the typos mean! I tried `vars<-deparse..` also and the exact error is: `Error in `[.data.frame`(test, , vars) : undefined columns selected`

Comment: I meant it would be `function(x){` instead of `function<-(x)`.  Also providing some example data and the package that has prediction function would be helpful

Comment: @akrun: I see the typo now! I don't know how I miss it! Thanks. BTW the prediction function is from ROCR package. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely need quotes when you call the function. Example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:4)
df
#  x
#1 1
#2 2
#3 3
#4 4
```

Create a simple function that returns a subset:

```
f <- function(x) df[,x]
```

And call the function to return the column `x`:

```
f(x)
#Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , x) : object 'x' not found
```

This is the error you received. The evaluator is looking for the object `x` and can't find it. Try:

```
f("x")
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

By quoting the column name we are able to locate the correct column. Hope that helps the issue.